# Chaining operator[] on nested map of struct

Tags: c++, std, stdmap

I have the following:

```
struct A { std::map<int, B> b; }
struct B { std::map<int, C> c; };
std::map<int, A> a;
```

And I would like to fill `a` with values inside a for loop:

```
for(int i : ...)
  for(int j : ...)
    for(int k : ...)
      a[i].b[j].c.emplace(k, <args to constructor of C>);
```

Is this inefficient? Will the A and B objects in the calls to `a[i]` and `b[j]` be constructed in-place? Does the answer depend on how often `a[i]` and `b[j]` result in an insert versus assign? Can this be done in a less-verbose manner using `try_emplace`?

Comment: Is `k` alwass unique, like `for k : { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }` or does the source have duplicates, like `for k : {1, 2, 3, 1, 2 }?

Comment: I would avoid repeatedly looking up `a[i]` and `a[i].b[j]` in the inner loop.

Comment: `Is this inefficient?` Yes. Well... depends of what you mean by "inefficient"

Comment: [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) has a note that says `operator[]` is equivalent to `return this->try_emplace(key).first->second;`, so there is no penalty in that sense.  However you are still doing that lookup on each iteration, which is slow (assuming it doesn't get optimized out).  Note that you might have better results with `std::unordered_map` since your key type is trivially hashable.

Answer (score 2):

#### Question

> Is this inefficient?

A little bit. You can store references to `a[i]` and `a[i].b[j]` locally to avoid mulitple calls.

```
for(int i : ...)
{
  auto& aref = a[i;
  for(int j : ...)
  {
    auto& bref = aref.b[j];
    for(int k : ...)
    {
      bref.c.emplace(k, <args to constructor of C>);
    }
  }
}
```

#### Question

> Will the A and B objects in the calls to a[i] and b[j] be constructed in-place?

Yes.

From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at:

> Inserts `value_type(key, T())` if the key does not exist.

#### Question

> Does the answer depend on how often a[i] and b[j] result in an insert versus assign?

No.

#### Question

> Can this be done in a less-verbose manner using try_emplace?

I am not clear what you are askig here.

Comment: [Tried it](https://godbolt.org/z/EACzOj). The version with references is 6 instructions shorter and has less branches, Tbh I thought it would get completely optimized.

Comment: @Timo, thanks. I am not assembly literate. I trust your assessment.

Comment: Neither am I. I just counted the instructions and the jump instructions and compared them.

Comment: When a function touches memory, it is hard for the compiler to infer what is going on. Operation `a[i].b[j].c.emplace` can potentially read *and* write to the same memory location. So the compiler doesn't really know that `a[i]` and `a[i].b[j]` is the same thing in the next loop iteration. Spelling it out explicitly to the compiler help things.